# Angular 9 get data with querystring params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular9

I am trying to get data from search API. The search value is passed as a query string.

No errors at compile time, no errors at runtime.

```js
const params = new HttpParams().set('search', 'pizza');
this.http
    .get('/hello', { responseType: 'json', params })
    .subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

Generates the `/hello` GET query but without the query string parameters.

What's wrong?

Angular exact version is 9.1.11

**EDIT**

The issue does not come from Angular but on how I try to embed the app. It works when using the default dev server without trying to embed it.

Comment: Try to specify the property: `{ responseType: 'json', params: params }`

Comment: `{params}` is a ES6 shortcut for `{params: params}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with Angular or the syntax I am using. The issue came from the integration I tried to do. I tried to embed the Angular App in a web page and develop from there.

It doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Everything work with the default dev server.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to specify which option to assign `params` to.

Try this:

```
const apiParams = new HttpParams().set('search', 'pizza');
this.http
    .get('/hello', { responseType: 'json', params: apiParams })
    .subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

Comment: what' different?

Comment: `params: apiParams`

Comment: oh right. syntax error. he just forgot to add ': params'

Comment: Yup. Please do accept the answer if it helped solve the issue.

Comment: This symtax is correct {params} as it is a ES6 shortcut for {params: params}

Comment: As Francois36 stated, he doesnt have to add the key explicitly, if the object refName is the same as the key would be.

Comment: No, the issue is not from Angular or the syntax I used. The issue came from how I embed it (maybe I should not). For now I am using the default dev server and everything work. Thanks for your help :)